# i7500 Unlock Button Broken

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-i7500

My i7500 doesn't unlock anymore (the screen unlock). I have a feeling the actual, physical button is broken, because the phone is on and responds to the power button being held down, but won't unlock.

Things I tried that failed:

- Rebooting does nothing.
- I tried the sqlite thing (updating one of the settings so that the phone doesn't lock by default or whatever), but my phone is not rooted, so I only got "access denied."
- I tried using adb shell to send the command `input keystate 82`, which supposedly  unlocks the phone, but nothing happened.
- Sending `event send EV_KEY:KEY_SOFT1:1` via adb (I get `access denied`).

If I can figure out how to unlock it once, I think I'm game. The phone runs a non-local version of Android 1.6. It's not rooted, sadly, and I really want to avoid formatting it if possible.

Here's what I'm doing right now:

- Install NoLock via adb: `adb install E:\download\NoLock1.05.apk`
- Run NoLock via adb: `adb shell am start -n org.jraf.android.nolock/org.jraf.android.nolock.activity.MainActivity` (prints `Starting: Intent {cmp=org.jraf.android.nolock/.activity/MainActivity }`)

So, if I can only unlock my phone now, and configure NoLock, I think I'm good.

How can I get my phone to unlock, and how can I then unlock it without the unlock key? Is the current path of nolock going to work?

Why doesn't sending `input keystate 82` unlock the screen?

Why doesn't NoLock automatically unlock the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me again. The process of unlocking was as follows:
- Call the Android phone from a normal phone
- Pick up the phone
- Press the options button
- Click the button to add someone to the call 
- Press the "go back" button

It should return you to the home page.

After that, setup Pattern Unlock. It only uses the touch-screen, so it works with a broken lock button.